# What is the purpose of slating a take when recording?

Tags: recording

What is the purpose of slating a take when recording a CD? For example, the producer might say:

> "Song A", Take 16, from measure 53.

Comment: Note, when this is done, it's almost always accompanied by someone taking notes about each take, including all the details and settings like mic position, amp settings, etc. Having a way to connect the written notes on the take with the audio from that take is required if those written notes are to be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To identify it when constructing the final mix.  Not much point in deciding "that was a good one!" if you can't find it later!

Comment: To add another "simple" point, it's improbable that *during the recording session* anybody will be splitting up the takes into separate audio files with meaningful names - better to just leave the recorders running and catch everything. That sort of grunt work can wait till later.